# Bypassing Fb Messenger

Tags: android

Is there any chance to bypass Fb messenger by getting reminders/event/alarm information being set on a group chat. I am planning to create an algorithm or an app that  automatically saves a reminders/event/alarm  so that later your phone will alarm even in offline. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well your question is quite broad.

By the way, if you're searching some way to get facebook events, alarms and reminders I suggest you to take a look to their [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/?locale=en_EN).

You can see [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/) to get started with the Android SDK.

You can query Facebook for all the information you need through the API, and then do your thing.

Disclaimer: I have no experience with this API, this is why I couldn't get you more help. 
I just pointed you what I thought you are needing.

I hope that this is what you're looking for!